# A loop in fortran code doesn't obey loop rules

Tags: while-loop, fortran, nested-loops

First of all i am new at fortran. I tried to find the value of 1/e within tolerance of 0.0000005. I used the summation representation of 1/e which is (epsilon) n from zero goes to infinity ((-1)^n)/n!. I started from n=2 and when the value of 1/n! is smaller than my tolerance, the program will stop and print the total value that is calculated. But my program just goes to n=3 only and only prints the value of 1/3! which is 1.666666. 
!program is edited. the edited form is calculates what i wanted.Before the condition of outer while was (num3<5e-8) and it didn't increase n. Now n increases problem is solved.

```
   program Ecalculator
   implicit none

   integer :: mult,num1,n,num4,num5
   real :: summ,num3,fact

   mult=1
   n=2.0
   fact=1.0
   summ=0.0

      DO WHiLE(n<13)
      fact=n
      num1=n-1

             DO WHiLE(num1>0)
             fact=fact*num1;
             num1=num1-1;

             END DO

       fact=fact*mult;
       num3=1.0/fact;
       mult=mult*(-1);
       summ=summ+num3;
       n=n+1;

        END DO

    print *, summ
    read  *, num5

    end program Ecalculator
```

Comment: It does not appear that you are initializing `num3` to anything. Even if it's guaranteed to be zero-initialized, it's quite possible you're not even entering your outer loop as a result...

Comment: `num1` is an integer, so `n-1` will also be an integer, although `n` is a real. Is that intended?

Comment: Also `REAL` doesn't have the precision you need. You need a double precision type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the factorial is not computed correctly: the line `fact=num4*num1` is probably not doing what you want, because `num4` is just assigned to be `n` and never changes throughout the inner loop. I don't think you need both variables `num4` and `fact`; you could combine them into one variable.

Comment: i changed the thing that you said about factorial loop and it calculates correct now. What about counting until 3. When n reaches to 3 the outer loop is suddenly broke.

Comment: Maybe `num3` is an integer instead of floating point as intended. You might try using `num3=1.0/fact` instead of `num3=1/fact`.

Comment: i tried what you said and changed the condition of outer loop from (num3<5e-7) to (n<12) now it calculates only n=2 and halts. Its is ridiciolus error.

Comment: Could you update your post to include the current version of your code?

Comment: thanks Brent Kerby. it is solved now. the updated program calculates now.